# How to properly decrypt in PHP using AES 256 while the encryption in Js

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography, aes, cryptojs

the encryption in the front end works but the decryption in the backend does not work.
I am using crypto JS for the front end and PHP in the back end. And I want to use AES-256

```
<script>
function encrypt(){
    passphrase= "123456";
    encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("decrypted soon", passphrase);
    return encrypted;
}
</script>
```

in PHP

```
public function decrypt ($encrypted)
      {
        $passphrase= "123456";
        $encrypted = base64_decode($encrypted);
        $decrypted = openssl_decrypt($encrypted, 'AES-256-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);
        return trim($decrypted);
      }
```

Your help is much appreciated

Comment: The CryptoJS code interprets `passphrase` as a passphrase, while the PHP code interprets `$passphrase` as a key (which may be padded or truncated). CryptoJS derives key and IV from the passphrase using the key derivation function `EVP_BytesToKey()`. This is missing in the PHP code, see for that part e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67811123/9014097). Once you have derived key and IV, you can use `openssl_decrypt()` to perform decryption. Note that `EVP_BytesToKey()` is deprecated ans insecure, you should better use a reliable key derivation function (e.g. PBKDF2).

Comment: If you want to encrypt data going from browser to server, just use HTTPS (which you should be doing anyway these days). The end user can see your encryption passphrase in the JS if they want to anyway, so this method is not very secure. It's hard to see what you think the benefits will be from what you're attempting

Comment: I just want to encrypt the data during transmission and then decrypt it in the back end.

Comment: HTTPS already does that for you, you don't need to write your own code for it.