# CryptoJS-AES CBC Decryption in PHP without IV

Tags: php, node.js, encryption, cryptojs

I have the following code in NodeJS

```js
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
const cfg = {
  mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
  padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
};
 encryptAES = (text, key) => {
    var encrypted =  CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text, key).toString();
    return encrypted;
  };
```

Once i encrypt any text with a 32 digit key, its encrypted and returned. I can decrypt it using the following function

```js
  decryptAES = (encryptedBase64, key) => {
    const decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedBase64, key);
    if (decrypted) {
      try {
        console.log(decrypted);
        const str = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
        if (str.length > 0) {
          return str;
        } else {
          return 'error 1';
        } 
      } catch (e) {
        return 'error 2';
      }
    }
    return 'error 3';
  };
```

Both encryption & decryption are working fine in react.

Example:

Text: this is a sample text
Key: 12345678123456781234567812345678
Result (encrypted): U2FsdGVkX1/ARpsMWWEdLiOanB67kh2akfCIN5s+RLDsJetSMagGsk444I+F/dbp

Now if i try to decrypt the above given encrypted text using PHP. I am getting `false` but nothing as decrypted.

PHP Code is as below:

```php
$key = '12345678123456781234567812345678';
$ciphertext = "U2FsdGVkX1/ARpsMWWEdLiOanB67kh2akfCIN5s+RLDsJetSMagGsk444I+F/dbp";
$result = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, 'AES-256-CBC', $key, 0);
while ($msg = openssl_error_string())
    echo $msg . "<br />\n";
var_dump($result);
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: If you pass the key material as a string in CryptoJS it will be interpreted as a password and a key derivation will be performed using the OpenSSL propietary function `EVP_BytesToKey()`. This is missing in the PHP code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert AES Decrypt from Javascript to php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67809175/how-to-convert-aes-decrypt-from-javascript-to-php)

Comment: Yes it does, please add a answer so i can accept it from yourside. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, I've added my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt()` the key material is passed as string, then it is interpreted as password and a key derivation is performed using the proprietary key derivation function `EVP_BytesToKey()` with MD5 as digest and an iteration count of 1.
The key derivation uses the password and a *randomly* generated 8 bytes salt to derive a 32 bytes key and a 16 bytes IV. The encrypted data is the concatenation of the ASCII encoding of `Salted__`, followed by the 8 bytes salt and followed by the actual ciphertext.

Therefore, during decryption, salt and actual ciphertext must first be extracted from the ciphertext. Then with salt and password the key and the IV must be determined using `EVP_BytesToKey()`, and finally the decryption can be performed:

```php
$password = '12345678123456781234567812345678';

// Extract IV and ciphertext
$saltCiphertextB64 = "U2FsdGVkX1/ARpsMWWEdLiOanB67kh2akfCIN5s+RLDsJetSMagGsk444I+F/dbp";
$saltCiphertext = base64_decode($saltCiphertextB64);
$salt = substr($saltCiphertext, 8, 8);
$ciphertext = substr($saltCiphertext, 16);

// Derive key and IV
$keyIv = EVP_BytesToKey($salt, $password);
$key = substr($keyIv, 0, 32);
$iv = substr($keyIv, 32);

// Decrypt
$result = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, 'AES-256-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
var_dump($result); // string(21) "this is a sample text"

function EVP_BytesToKey($salt, $password) {
    $derived = '';
    $tmp = '';
    while(strlen($derived) < 48) {
        $tmp = md5($tmp . $password . $salt, true);
        $derived .= $tmp;
    }
    return $derived;
}
```

Comment: and for the encryption we will be using the same method in reverse?

Comment: @Ahsan - Yes, more precisely, for encryption with PHP analogous to CryptoJS: 1. generate a *random* 8 bytes salt, 2. derive a 32 bytes key and 16 bytes IV with `EVP_BytesToKey()` analogous to decryption, and 3. use these to perform encryption with AES-256-CBC. Finally the result is to be formatted OpenSSL conform, as Base64 encoding of the concatenation: *Salted__ + salt + ciphertext*.